# How does this lambda print the list in reverse? I am unsure what the purpose of the 100/x line is

Tags: python

This is the code I've used to reverse and print the list. Though it is correct I do not understand exactly why. I have tried changing the value but as of yet am unable to see how the lambda is working.

```
lst=[2,4,6,8,10]

lst.sort(key=lambda x: 100/x)

print(lst)
```

#Output: [10, 8, 6, 4, 2]

Comment: Could you add the output?

Comment: this lambda doesn't print anything, this lambda is used to create a key function. Do you understand what the `key=` paramter does in `list.sort`?

Comment: `100/x` is an example of an expression that produces smaller outputs for larger inputs.  `-x` would be a simpler way of accomplishing the same thing - or you could simply use the `reverse=True` parameter to `.sort()`.

Comment: Note that this won't work when the list contains negative numbers too.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. This is much clearer to me now.

Comment: notice that using the reciprocal (or similar) as an ordering criteria may lead to unwanted behavior, in particular when x big or too small due to _float_ limitations. try smt like _e**(-x!)_

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your visualization, you can `map()` the lambda function on your list to see the result of the lambda function on each item of your list:

```py
>>> lst=[2,4,6,8,10]
>>> print(list(map((lambda x: (x, 100/x)), lst)))
[(2, 50.0), (4, 25.0), (6, 16.6), (8, 12.5), (10, 10.0)]
```

And so, the `list.sort()`/`sorted()` functions will sort the list according to the results of the lambda function, which are `[50.0, 25.0, 16.6, 12.5, 10.0]`.

The `sort()` function will apply the lambda function on the `key=` parameter onto every item of the list and sort the results.

It's also important to note that this code **does not reverse any list**. It only reverses this list by chance. To truly sort any list, set the `reverse=True`parameter on the `list.sort()` call.

Answer (score 0):

It's purely a math thing: the function 1/x (or 100/x, there's no reason why it needs to be 100, it can be any positive number) maps very large numbers to numbers close to 0, and numbers close to 0 to very large numbers. Try it yourself:

```
1000 -> 1/1000 = 0.001
100  ->  1/100 = 0.01
10   ->   1/10 = 0.1
and as we approach 0,
0    ->    1/0 tends towards infinity
```

So when you do `key=lambda x: 1/x`, you're making large numbers small and small numbers large, so when you sort them, the order is flipped! But as you saw, 0 is an edge case. You cannot divide by 0. The solution is to use another such function that has the same property (large numbers map to small numbers), and one such function is `lambda x: -x`. This does not break when you try to sort 0.

(But like Rafael de Bem said, you should not use something like this to reverse a list. There are things like `lst.sort(reverse=True)` which are more pythonic.)

Answer (score 0):

I see allot of answers but i'll give it to you in simple terms, you made every big number small, and every small number big, then sorted by that, so basically what you did was sort from largest to smallest

this only reversed your list because it was previously sorted smallest to largest, if you changed the original order, the output would remain the same